# TwitterAuth.php error

Tags: php, api, twitter

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in path/TwitterOAuth.php on line 129

```
public function oauth($path, array $parameters = [])
```

Guys! What this? Its really fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a PHP version that is way too old for anything, these days.

Defining arrays with `[]` is only supported from PHP 5.4 as mentioned on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) page:

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

Comment: Thanky! All work, with replace `[]` on `array()`

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above answers not working check whether the function resides in any of the classes. Otherwise remove the access specifier public from function definition.

```
function oauth($path, array $parameters = [])
```